# upload a file from aws lambda to aws s3 -without using aws-sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-landing-zone

I want to perform some lambda function to upload files to s3.
I found that using aws-sdk taking too much space for me. so i try to upload with pure node without any libary that not build in.

this is the code that run on aws lambda function:

```
//My file:
const buffer = await downloadFile(url); // file is gz file downloaded as buffer

    const endpoint = `https://${myBucket}.s3.${myRegion}.amazonaws.com/${store}/${file_name}.gz`;
    const options = {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "Content-Encoding": "gzip",
        "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(buffer),
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
      },
    };

const data = await uploadFile(endpoint, options, buffer);
```

and the upload function is :

```
const uploadFile = (endpoint, options, buffer) => {
  const s3UploadRequest = https.request(endpoint, options, (res) => {
    console.log(`Status code: ${res.statusCode}`);
    console.log(`Status message: ${res.statusMessage}`);
    res.on("data", (chunk) => {
      console.log(`Response: ${chunk}`);
    });
    res.on("end", () => {
      if (res.statusCode > 400 && res) console.log("Upload FAILED");
      else console.log("Upload complete");
    });
  });

  s3UploadRequest.on("error", (error) => {
    console.error(`Error uploading to S3: ${error}`);
  });

  s3UploadRequest.write(buffer);
  s3UploadRequest.end();
};
```

and im getting
"`AccessDenied`Access DeniedsomeIdidLc/largeStringWithManyChars="

The issue is when i run this code using aws-sdk it works fine , but i dont know how to make a simple upload without this libary. (also used documention [aws_doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) but didnt help me)

Comment: What do you mean by "taking too much space for me"?

Comment: You need to get the [role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) and [sign](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RESTAuthentication.html) the call to S3, depending on the size of the upload, you may need to call [CreateMultipartUpload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CreateMultipartUpload.html) and related APIs.  Or, just use the SDK.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein , the size of the packge is 85mb . if just take the relvant script it will be around 5kb (with all other files) . i know it is not the memory size for payment calculation but its crucial for me.

Comment: @AnonCoward i cant see how it answere what i ask. can u provide me an example ?

Comment: My attempt was to guide to a possible solution, I'm not going to provide a working example, perhaps someone else can.  It's a non-trivial amount of work.  Any solution I write for production purposes would use the SDK instead of recreating it.

Comment: If you want to write it yourself, see: [Authenticating Requests (AWS Signature Version 4) - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) However, it is much better to use the AWS SDK that is already available.

Comment: is not a simpler way ? for simple uses we need to use all the libary? 
i have some lambda functions that each use different single function from aws-sdk.
uploading the entire packges seems not so efficent.